# It seems like malloc is asking for too much memory

Tags: gcc, malloc, sbrk

I have an STM32F0 application using the yagarto GCC compiler.  I've implemented _sbrk newlib_stubs.c.  The problem I'm running into is I'm calling malloc(256) an in-turn malloc in invoking _sbrk and asking for 4K of memory.  My system only has a total of 8K so obviously this is a problem.  I've monitored calls to _sbrk and it seems to make a few calls prior to this allocating smaller amounts of memory.

Right now I'm getting around this by holding my nose to avoid the stench and doing something like:

```
if(requested > 512)
    requested = 512;
```

in _sbrk before I reposition the heap.

Although the system seems rock solid, I'm fairly certain this is going to come back and haunt me when I least expect it.

Comment: Where does the `malloc()` implementation come from?

Comment: Comes from an library implemented in assembler that's part of the YAGARTO tool chain.  Next step would be to crack open the source for that.

Comment: Seems like something that *might* make sense for a desktop/server OS, but it seems weird for a microcontroller. (In fact in a system with 8K of RAM, `malloc()` itself seems kind-of weird, but I'm pretty old-school.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the subtle hints provided in the comments about not using malloc, I just ended up creating something to allocate my own memory.  I don't ever need to release it so that made it simple.  Only thing that stung me for about an hour was maintain the 32 bit alignment.

Here's my implementation pm_ stands for poor mans.

```
#define HEAPSIZE 0x800 //2K

    uint16_t __heapPtr = 0;
    uint8_t __customHeap[HEAPSIZE];
    void *pm_malloc(uint16_t size){
        while(__heapPtr % 4 != 0)
            __heapPtr++;

        void *block = &__customHeap[__heapPtr];
        if(size + __heapPtr > HEAPSIZE)
            return 0;

        __heapPtr += size;
        return block;
    }
```

My life has been C#, Java and Objective-C for the past 15 years, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an old post, and I don't know much about your platform, but would something like alloca be an option? It does dynamic allocation on the stack and frees it when the function returns. Not portable, but if it is available, it might be worth looking into.